# ionic, list items with icon on the left and icon on the right

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to make a list of links with icons on the right and icons on the left.

Can you help me clean this ?

http://codepen.io/LouisDoe/pen/MyyONK?editors=1000

code:

```
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#" ng-click="goToNextSlide()">
                        <i class="icon ion-male blueicon"></i>
                         Woman
                        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#" ng-click="goToNextSlide()">
                        <i class="icon ion-female blueicon"></i>
                         Man
                        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the class `item` to the `ion-item` elements like so:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#" ng-click="goToNextSlide()">
        <i class="icon ion-male blueicon"></i>
        Woman
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#" ng-click="goToNextSlide()">
        <i class="icon ion-female blueicon"></i>
        Man
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKKogv?editors=1000